# RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, ppa, 16.04, git, rabbitvcs

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I would like to install RabbitVCS on my system.

I already add the PPA and apt update and seem no build yet for xenial

1. http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
2. http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages

How to contact the maintainer? Does anyone have working deb file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `rabbitvcs` package is within the official repositories so remove the ppa's again and make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16140883/). Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs*
```

If you run into following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/.config/rabbitvcs/settings.conf
```

simply correct the permissions by :

```
sudo chown "$USER" .config/rabbitvcs -R
```

Comment: Thank! It work.. but seem need i need to give owner permisssion to configuration file :
`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/.config/rabbitvcs/settings.conf`

after chmod with `sudo chown username:groupname .config/rabbitvcs -R` and now It worked!

Comment: If my answer is correct and helped you, you could accept it. Added your information to my answer.

Comment: Done. If my question are clear and useful. +1 rep for me, so I can vote people who help me. Currently my rep point are 8..so I cant vote the best answer.

Comment: Fixed the same issue in `18.04`