# rabbit vcs context menu not showing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rabbitvcs

I am unable to see the rabbit vcs context menu in the file manager window

ubuntu 16.04

rabbitvcs installed via xenial repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve it, I uninstalled the RabbitCVS

```
sudo apt-get remove rabbitvcs*
```

installed again

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs*
```

and changed assigned permission to config file

```
sudo chown YOURUSERNAME .config/rabbitvcs -R
```

(please change YOURUSERNAME with your user name :D ).

This worked for me.

Originally posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766213/rabbitvcs-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts?rq=1)