# Rabbist VCS stopped showing up

Tags: nautilus, svn, rabbitvcs

Recently, `Rabbit VCS` stopped showing up in `nautilus`. Tried [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772574/rabbit-vcs-context-menu-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107813/rabbitvcs-gui-does-not-appear), no help.

I have `Ubuntu 18.04` with `GNOME Shell 3.28.4`

This is what I get:

```
RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file
ERROR   rabbitvcs.services.checkerservice   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.google.code.rabbitvcs.RabbitVCS.Checker was not provided by any .service files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/services/checkerservice.py", line 265, in _connect_to_checker
    OBJECT_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.google.code.rabbitvcs.RabbitVCS.Checker was not provided by any .service files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.status_checker.assert_version(EXT_VERSION)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/services/checkerservice.py", line 280, in assert_version
    pid = self.status_checker.CheckVersionOrDie(version)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CheckVersionOrDie'
```

[This method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062947/rabbit-vcs-on-ubuntu-18-04-not-showing-menu-in-nautilus/1062953#1062953) also doesn't help. I get:

```
ERROR   rabbitvcs.services.checkerservice   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.google.code.rabbitvcs.RabbitVCS.Checker was not provided by any .service files
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/services/check
erservice.py", line 265, in _connect_to_checker
```

Any ideas on how to get it showing up?

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1062953/66509 .

Comment: @N0rbert That has no effect