# Python plugins not working after switching to Python 3

Tags: python, gedit, plugins, svn

In particular, the very nice [join lines](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome/gedit-plugin-join-lines) for `gedit`.

I have a suspicion that it all started when I installed Python3.7 and switched to it by default.

Somehow, other things stopped working also, like [Rabbit VCS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257993/rabbist-vcs-stopped-showing-up).

Is there a kind of a Python version clash or something? I can't find anything related.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jul  2 11:36 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3637096 Apr 15 20:20 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr 15 20:20 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Apr 18 04:56 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr 18 04:56 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Apr 18 04:56 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Apr 18 04:56 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4873376 Nov  7  2019 /usr/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4873376 Nov  7  2019 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

Comment: Don't just 'switch' python versions without being smart about it.  Did you switch Python 2 to Python 3 completely?  Don't do that since 18.04 has a bunch of Python2 dependencies still for scripts, programs, etc.

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't know exactly what is meant by "switching completely", but I simply installed Python3.7. `update-alternatives --config python` seems not to list Python2.7, however. Strange

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Well ... it feels messed up. `/usr/bin/python` calls `python3.7`, whereas `/usr/bin/python3` calls `python3.6`. That's not right, right?

Comment: Sounds like you replaced python2 with python 3.7. Best idea is to delete 3.7 and try reinstalling python2. You may need to reinstall. Learn about python virtual environments to use other versions of python 3.

Comment: @Eagle_Mike I do use virtual environments, but was apparently a bit ignorant of possible issues - thought installing python3 wouldn't cause troubles. Do you mean you can't have two pythons alongside in Ubuntu? Would adding python2.7 to `update-alternatives` not suffice? Actually, I'd appreciate a couple more details in an answer.

Comment: @RubiShnol: Can you please edit your question and include the output from this terminal command: `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Done!

Comment: @RubiShnol: Hmm.. The question was closed due to the duplicate I pointed at. But a simple way to fix it for you is to change the `python` symlink directly: `sudo rm /usr/bin/python && sudo ln -s python2 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Would you mind to help with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257993/rabbist-vcs-stopped-showing-up?noredirect=1#comment2125997_1257993)? I thought fixing the symlink would remedy that, but nothing changed

Comment: @RubiShnol: Sorry, but that's over my head. You can always try to reinstall, of course: `sudo apt install --reinstall rabbitvcs-nautilus`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Wow! It worked)

Comment: @RubiShnol: Sometimes you are lucky. :)